# Какое правило можно применить к использованию частицы "не" и наречию "непосредственно", в таком случае "не непосредственно"?

Tags: частица-не

В действующем ГОСТе 12.2.091-2012 (IEC 61010-1:2001) от 2014-01-01 вычитал такое вот предложение:

"Категория измерений I предназначена для измерений, выполняемых в цепях, не непосредственно подключенных к сети."

Каким правилом можно обосновать или ,наоборот, запретить употребление "не непосредственно" в данном предложении?

Answer (score 1):

А в чём проблема? *"Непосредственно"* — обычное прилагательное, *"не"* — обычная отрицательная частица, никаких особых правил тут нет. Здесь подразумевается противопоставление: не непосредственно, а опосредованно.